# Closing a div by clicking outside and clicking a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, onclick, addeventlistener

i am trying to setup a dropdown menu, that can be closed by clicking outside (the opened div) and by clicking the button/img (that opens the div).

Image with onclick funtion:

```
<img onclick="hide()" id="menu" src="....">
```

Dropdown list that should be opened and closed, class declares dropdown as **display:none**:

```
<ul id="dropdown" class="dropdown-breadcrumb">
   <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

This is my solution so far:

```
function hide() {
    var x = document.getElementById("dropdown");

    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

When i am trying to add a function that closes the dropdown when the user clicks outside the dropdown:

```
window.addEventListener('mouseup',function(event){
        var dropd = document.getElementById('dropdown');

        if(event.target != dropd && event.target.parentNode != dropd){
            dropd.style.display = 'none';
        }
});
```

Then i end up with a opened dropdown because the onclick-function starts.

Can someone help me to combine those functions? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could bring all of your logic to the click listener and handle the elements' visibility in the function:

```js
window.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
  var dropd = document.getElementById('dropdown');
  var img = document.getElementById('menu');

  if (event.target === img && dropd.style.display === "none") {
    dropd.style.display = "block";
  } else if (event.target != dropd && event.target.parentNode != dropd) {
    dropd.style.display = 'none';
  }
});
```

```html
<img id="menu" alt="img" />
<ul id="dropdown" class="dropdown-breadcrumb" style="width: 40px;">
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you very much (Y)

Comment: @JohnDoe glad I could help :)

Comment: Inside our <li>-Tag we have a hyperlink, when you click the hyperlink, the dropdown closes. Any idea?

Comment: @JohnDoe because `event.target` is am anchor tag, you can change the condition to `if ((event.target === img || event.target.tagName == "A") && dropd.style.display === "none")` to make it work for anchor tags

Comment: Sorry for beeing stupid, but still does'nt work .. 

`window.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
  var dropd = document.getElementById('dropdown');
  var img = document.getElementById('menu');

  if ((event.target === img || event.target.tagName === "A") && dropd.style.display === "none") {
    dropd.style.display = 'block';
  } else if (event.target != dropd && event.target.parentNode != dropd) {
    dropd.style.display = 'none';
  }
});`

Comment: it is failing because `dropd.style.display` is `block`, use `if ((event.target === img) && dropd.style.display === "none" || (event.target.tagName === "A" && dropd.style.display === "block")) {`, my bad

Comment: You're my hero ! Thank you ! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also try this one.

```
  $(window).click(function() { //Hide the menus if visible });
```